problem justifying menu items left and right in a navbar
I have the following html that displays what I want, but not where I want it ;-).  I want the File drop-down on the left and the rest of the drop-downs on the right.  I've included my css files as they may be interfering with my me-auto tags in the class definition.  I've included the reference to bootstrap here (it didn't help) but it's included in other code,


    /* menu.css */
    .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-item {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top; 
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-item .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3498db;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(100% + 5px);
        left: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: #333;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }


    /* styles.css */
    body {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    body.debug {
        background-image: url('/static/images/background-debug.jpg');
    }
    
    body.production {
        background-image: url('/static/images/background.jpg');
    }
    
    * {
        border: none !important;
    }
    
    .custom-dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
        background-color: white !important;
    }
    
    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
    .form-wrapper {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form .form-group {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form label {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form input, .form-wrapper form select {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #333;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form input:focus, .form-wrapper form select:focus {
        border-color: #333;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form button {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form button:disabled {
        background-color: #999;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form input {
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #333;
        outline: none;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper form button:hover {
        background-color: #555;
    }
    
    .error {
        font-size: 14px; /* Smaller font size for error messages */
        color: red; /* Error messages in red */
        font-weight: bold; /* Bold error messages */
        word-wrap: break-word; /* Wrap long error messages */
    }
    
    #show-password {
        margin-left: 5px; /* Add some space between password input and toggle */
        width: 20px; /* Increase width of toggle */
        height: 20px; /* Increase height of toggle */
    }
    .form-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        max-width: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .form-group label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .form-group input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .qr-code img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 50%; /* Adjusted size to half */
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
    }
    
    button[type="submit"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #007BFF;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    button[type="submit"]:disabled {
        background-color: #ccc;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
      <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <div class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-between">
        <!-- File Dropdown -->
        <div class="nav-item dropdown ms-auto">
            <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="fileDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                File
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="fileDropdown">
                {% if management_company is none %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="createManagementCompany">Create Management Company</a>
                {% elif multiple_companies %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/manage_management_companies">Management Company: {{ management_company }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="dropdown-item disabled">Management Company: {{ management_company }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Security Dropdown -->
        <div class="nav-item dropdown me-auto">
            <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="securityDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Security
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="securityDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/authentication">Authentication</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/forgot_password">Change password</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Help Dropdown -->
        <div class="nav-item dropdown me-auto">
            <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="helpDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Help
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="helpDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/about">About</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




If you want the three dropdowns to be on one "row", adding the flex-row class to the outer div seems to help:


/* menu.css */
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-item .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #333;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}


/* styles.css */
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body.debug {
    background-image: url('/static/images/background-debug.jpg');
}

body.production {
    background-image: url('/static/images/background.jpg');
}

* {
    border: none !important;
}

.custom-dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    background-color: white !important;
}

.form-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.form-wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-wrapper form .form-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper form label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper form input, .form-wrapper form select {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
}

.form-wrapper form input:focus, .form-wrapper form select:focus {
    border-color: #333;
    outline: none;
}

.form-wrapper form button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper form button:disabled {
    background-color: #999;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.form-wrapper form input {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
}

.form-wrapper form button:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.error {
    font-size: 14px; /* Smaller font size for error messages */
    color: red; /* Error messages in red */
    font-weight: bold; /* Bold error messages */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Wrap long error messages */
}

#show-password {
    margin-left: 5px; /* Add some space between password input and toggle */
    width: 20px; /* Increase width of toggle */
    height: 20px; /* Increase height of toggle */
}
.form-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.form-wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-group input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.qr-code img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 50%; /* Adjusted size to half */
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #007BFF;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button[type="submit"]:disabled {
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <div class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <!-- File Dropdown -->
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="fileDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            File
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="fileDropdown">
            {% if management_company is none %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="createManagementCompany">Create Management Company</a>
            {% elif multiple_companies %}
                <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/manage_management_companies">Management Company: {{ management_company }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <span class="dropdown-item disabled">Management Company: {{ management_company }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Security Dropdown -->
    <div class="nav-item dropdown me-auto">
        <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="securityDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Security
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="securityDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/authentication">Authentication</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/forgot_password">Change password</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log out</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Help Dropdown -->
    <div class="nav-item dropdown me-auto">
        <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="helpDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Help
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="helpDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/about">About</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Unfortunately that didn't make a difference for me.  I tried deleting the contents of my css files to remove any possible conficts and that didn't help either
